# Taking Screenshots Using Qt C++ on Android

Tags: android, c++, qt, screenshot

thanks for checking my question out!

I'm currently working on a project using Qt C++, which is designed to be multi-platform. I'm a bit of a newcoming to it, so I've been asked to set up the ability to take screenshots from within the menu structure, and I'm having issues with the Android version of the companion app.

As a quick overview, it's a bit of software that send the content of a host PC's screen to our app, and I've been able to take screenshots on the Windows version just fine, using QScreen and QPixmap, like so:

overlaywindow.cpp

```
{
    QPixmap screenSnapData = screenGrab->currentBackground();
}
```

screenGrabber.cpp

```
{
    QScreen *screen = QGuiApplication::primaryScreen();
    return screen->grabWindow( QApplication::desktop()->winId() );
}
```

Unfortunately, Android seems to reject QScreen, and with most suggestions from past Google searches suggesting the now-deprecated QPixmap::grab(), I've gotten a little stuck.

What luck I *have* had is within the code for the menu itself, and QWidget, but that isn't without issue, of course!

```
QFile doubleCheckFile("/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/Testing/checking.png");
doubleCheckFile.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite);
QPixmap checkingPixmap = QWidget::grab();
checkingPixmap.save(&doubleCheckFile);
doubleCheckFile.close();
```

This code does take a screenshot, but only of the button strip currently implemented, and not for the whole screen. I've also taken a 'screenshot' of just a white box with the screen's dimensions by using:

```
QDesktopWidget dw;
QWidget *screen=dw.screen();         
QPixmap checkingPixmap = screen->grab();
```

Would anyone know of whether there was an alternative to using QScreen to take a screenshot in Android, or whether there's a specific way to get it working as compared to Windows? Or would QWidget be the right track? Any help's greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

as i can read in [Qt doc](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-desktop-screenshot-example.html) : In your screenGrabber.cpp :

```
QScreen *screen = QGuiApplication::primaryScreen();
return screen->grabWindow( QApplication::desktop()->winId() );
```

replace with :

```
QScreen *screen = QGuiApplication::primaryScreen();
return screen->grabWindow( 0 ); // as 0 is the id of main screen
```

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work for the Android version, as it's still using QScreen, as shown with the following compiler error:
could not convert 'QScreen::grabWindow(WId, int, int, int, int)(0u, 0, 0, -1, -1)' from 'QPixmap' to 'QScreen'
     return screen->grabWindow( 0 );

Answer (score 0):

If you want to take a screenshot of your own widget, you can use the method `QWidget::render` ([Qt Doc](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#render)):

```
QPixmap pixmap(widget->size());
widget->render(&pixmap);
```

If you want to take a screenshot of another app/widget than your app, you should use the Android API...

Answer (score 0):

I was doing this example today and noticed that the Android version doesn't work right. I need to split screen my app with another.  Then take a whole snapshot so that I can parse the other window for data for my app.  It is a diabetes app and I need to get data from My Fitness Pal into my app.  [My app in split screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oD1kS.png).  This not good.  I can call out the android version of take screen shot but I am sticking in Qt mainly and not trying to bring in Java.

Comment: Hi Chris! Welcome to SO and thank you for the contribution. However, I do not understand how this answer fits to the question asked. Please edit your answer.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Actually I am not answering the question but adding to it.  I want to take a whole screen shot in Android but the "example" from Qt doesn't work.